# Battery won't charge when ON, Arch Linux

Tags: laptop, battery

I run Arch Linux 5.5.13 on my laptop. A year ago, I changed the original battery for a new one (maybe not the official one).

It has been some time that I have the same problem. Charging the battery requires I either a) turn off my laptop, or b) close the lid.

`acpi -i` returns

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 17%, 00:32:27 remaining
Battery 0: design capacity 2600 mAh, last full capacity 2214 mAh = 85%
```

`acpi -a` returns `Adapter 0: off-line` even when adpater is plugged.

I tried to check at results for `dmesg | grep acpi` :

```
[    0.046425] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] high level lint[0x1])
[    0.046427] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x03] high level lint[0x1])
[    0.046429] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x04] high level lint[0x1])
[    0.472516] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    1.220166] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
[    1.220571] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[    1.220604] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    1.436438] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
```

I can get for half a second in xfce4 battery status panel (or with `acpi -a`)  a charging icon when I plug back the adapter.

I was not able to see where the problem is coming from. Any suggestion for further investigation ?